# Build Material UI TextField component in Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, redux-form

Could someone please show me how to build a TextField component using Redux Form ***WITHOUT*** the `{...input}`, e.g:

```
const renderTextField = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom }) => (
  <TextField hintText={label}
    floatingLabelText={label}
    errorText={touched && error}
    {...input}
    {...custom}
  />
)
```

The Field can't get any focus because of some bug in the input variable, and I can't figure out how to build the component using the input methods and values to work around the bug(possibly). Please some help! :(

Comment: Have you tried the Material Ui wrapper components? https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui

Comment: Thanks for the link, really helpful!